# What will be a faster algorithm that finds the maximum number of party people?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

You want to organize a party and invite as many of your **N** friends as possible so that the following condition is met: at a party, everyone invited must know at least three other guests and must not be familiar with at least three other guests.

**Question:** what is the fastest algorithm that receives a list of couples of people who know each other and determines the maximum number of people for a party? Estimate the time for which the algorithm works. Argue your assessment.

**My idea**: create a matrix of size N by N, and fill it with links from the condition. After that, you need to remove from it all the connections of people who have less than three friends, it takes $N^2$ operations. Then we get new number of  ${N_{1}} \leq N $.
After which I experience difficulties. Obviously, if one goes through the $ 2 ^ {N_{1}} $ cases from the remaining friends, then one can get the maximum.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.

Comment: I have only one idea, but it forks for $n^2$.

Comment: @Discretelizard any idea?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко I just edited the post so that there is a **question**. The question might be obvious to you; however, it is better to be explicit. Please correct my modification as you please.

Comment: @Apass.Jack This question is formulated in paragraph 2 of my post.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко Paragraph 2 of the post is usually called problem statement. It is not your question proper. However, the question in the latest version of the post is OK unless you will be held to a higher standard.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Get your point. This is a question from one entrance exam. I do not know what complexity met the criteria for the maximum ball. But I think that $O(N ^ 2)$ is enough. Did I understand correctly from the answer below that at worst the complexity of $O(N + M)$ would turn into $O(N ^ 2)$?

Comment: No. The worst time-complexity of the algorithm given by George Vidalakis's answer is $O(N+M)$, which is basically the best you can hope in big $O$-notation under the assumption that the length of input is $O(N+M)$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack but $M \sim N^2$?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко $M$ could be approximately equal to $N^2$, but this doesn't always hold. For example there are graphs where $M = O(N)$. If no relation between these two variables is specified by the problem statement one should not assume one by him/herself. And as $O(M) \subseteq O(N^2)$ the second algorithm I described is always asymptotically at least as fast as the first one and as a result it should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I will provide a solution for your problem with $O(N^2)$ computational complexity and $O(N^2)$ space complexity.
Firstly we will introduce some helpfull notation. Let's name $A$ the set of your $N$ friends. Let's also define a boolean function $P(x, S)$ with two parameters, $x$ which is one of your friends and a set of your friends $S \subseteq A: x \in S$. $P(x, S)$ will be true iff $x$ knows at least three people in $S$ and he/she also doesn't know at least three people in $S$. Finally, we define that the boolean function $V(S)$ where $S \subseteq A$ will be true iff $x \in S \Rightarrow P(x, S)$. In other words, $V(S)$ shows if a set of people, $S$, can be the guests of your party. The answer to your problem is the value of the following expression:
$$\max_{S \subseteq A \\ V(S) = true} |S|$$
Now we will make a usefull observation: If a person $x$ doesn't have at least three known and three unknown people in a set of some of your friends, then he will not have at least three known and three unknown people in any subset of that set. This could be written as
$$\forall S \subseteq A, T \subseteq S, x \in T: \neg P(x, S) \Rightarrow \neg P(x, T)$$
This means that removing guests can't make the party proper for someone if it's not already, or equivalently that the only way to make the party proper for someone (if it is not already) is by inviting more guests (and that will not always work).

Now we can construct a solution for your problem. We will initially assume that all of your friends are invited. If the required condition follows for all of them then we are done. Otherwise the party is not proper for some of your friends and as we can not add more guests to make it proper we must remove them from the party. We select one of them randomly and we remove him/her. This may make the party improper for even more guests, so we will have to remove them too. We keep removing guests one by one until the party is proper for every remaining guest. The number of the remaining guests is the answer to your problem.

This algorithm works fine. An efficient way to implement it is to have an $N \times N$ adjacency matrix in which we store binary information about "who knows who" (anti-reflexive, symmetric relationship) and $N$ pairs of integers that denote how many known and unknown people of every guest are currently at the party. These structures are initialized when you read the input. We can also have a set structure (e.g. a queue) where we insert a guest's id when we find out that the party is improper for him/her and a boolean array of size $N$ that stores who is currently invited. We pop elements from the set in order to remove the guests. When we remove a guest we update the pair of ints of every other guest according to if they know each other or not. When after an update the party is improper for a guest we insert him/her to the set in order to remove him/her later and we mark his/her position in the boolean arra to know that this guest will not be invited. When the set is empty there are no more guests to be removed so we can count how many guests are still invited to your party using the boolean array. The number of the counted invited guests is the answer.

Reading the input and initialization of the data structures has $O(N^2)$ computational complexity. We will remove at most $N$ guests and for each removal we check/update $O(N)$ values. So the total computational complexity of our algorithm is $O(N^2)$. The space complexity is also $O(N^2)$ as a result of the adjacency matrix.

Below I provide a C++ code that solves your problem using the described algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 105  // Maximum number of friends possible

bool adj[MAXN][MAXN];  // Adjacency matrix
// adj[x][y] = true iff x and y know each other

bool INV[MAXN];  // INV[x] = true iff x is invited to the party

int K[MAXN], U[MAXN];
// Counters for known and unknown invited guests for each guest

queue<int> Q;
// Queue with the ids of the guests that should be removed

int main()
{
    // Reding input and initializations...
    int N;  // Number of your friends
    // Assume ids in range 0 to N-1 inclusive
    cin >> N;
    int M;  // Number of connections
    cin >> M;

    // Before the connections are known to us we assume that everyone knows noone
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) U[i] = N - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        adj[x][y] = adj[y][x] = true;  // x and y know each other
        // Update number of known/unknown guests for x and y
        K[x]++;
        K[y]++;
        U[x]--;
        U[y]--;
    }

    // Initially everyone is assumed to be invited
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) INV[i] = true;

    // Find guests that should be removed (phase 1)...
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (K[i] < 3 || U[i] < 3)
        {
            // The party is improper for current guest
            // Save his id in the queue to remove him/her later
            Q.push(i);
            INV[i] = false;  // The guest should not be invited
        }
    }

    // Remove guests until the party is ok for everyone
    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        int rem_guest = Q.front();  // Id of a guest that we should remove
        Q.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (INV[i])
        {
            // The number of known or unknown guests for current guest is decreased
            if (adj[rem_guest][i]) K[i]--;
            else U[i]--;
            if (K[i] < 3 || U[i] < 3)
            {
                // The party is improper for current guest
                // Save his id in the queue to remove him/her later
                Q.push(i);
                INV[i] = false;  // The guest should not be invited
            }
        }
    }

    int ans = 0;  // The result variable
    // Count guests that will be invited
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (INV[i]) ans++;

    // Display answer
    cout << ans << '\n';

    return(0);
}
```

Edit:

It is also possible to construct a solution with $O(N + M)$ computational and space complexity, where $M$ is the number of connections between your friends. The main idea remains the same, you initially assume that everyone is going to be a guest and then you start to remove guests until the party is proper for everyone. What we will change is the information we keep. Let's observe why the complexity of the previous solution was $O(N^2)$.

The first reason was that we used an adjacency matrix. By replacing this structure with adjacency lists we drop the space complexity of the whole algorithm and the computational complexity of the initialization to $O(N + M)$. Note that our algorithm has nothing to lose from such a conversion. Even with no further changes we can use the adjacency lists as we used the adjacency matrix before. That's because the only use of it was to classify all of our friends to known and unknown people of a guest when this guest was removed. This can also be done if we create a boolean array of size $N$ which we initialize to false and we make true the values of it that appear in the adjacency list of the guest being removed. After that this array is equal to the row of the removed guest in the adjacency matrix that now doesn't exist (we will not do something like that, it is only used to show that in our case adjacency matrix is not needed). So there is no reason not to replace the adjacency matrix.

The second reason why the time complexity of our algorithm was $O(N^2)$ is that we updated the number of known and unknown guests of each guest every time a guest was removed, which required $O(n)$ updates. An additional observation we can make is that the number of the unknown guests of a guest can be inferred by the number of his/her known guests if we also know which is the current number of total guests, by executing a simple subtraction. Also note that, excluding the first identification of which guests should be removed (which was done after reading the input and making the initializations), after every guest removal there is a specific number of known or unknown guest of every guest that will have to be removed cause of the described removal. Specifically, if after a guest removal $L$ more guests are still invited, it is enough to check which guests have $2$ or $L - 3$ known still invited guests. These guests should be removed because they don't have enough known (in the first case) or unknown (in the second case) invited guests. In order to take advantage of these observations we can create a size $N$ array of lists where at $i$-th position we will have a list (double linked) with the ids of the not yet to be removed guests with $i$ known guests. This allows us to see which guests have exactly $3$ or $L - 3$ known guests in the party at every moment. By adding a size $N$ array of list iterators (one for every guest with the iterator showing his/her id position in the appropriate list of the previous array) we can achive $O(1)$ list change for every guest.

So the changes to the previous algorithm are the following: Use adjacency lists instead of matrix, the array of lists and the array of iterators as described above. Every time you remove a guest move all his/her known people from their current list to the previous one and then add all guests who are in list $2$ or $L - 3$ in the "to-be-removed" set and delete them from the respective list (so that you don't see them again there). You will make $O(M)$ replacements and $O(N)$ deletions in $O(1)$ each. The total computational and space complexity of the algorithm is $O(N + M)$ which is better than $O(N^2)$ for sparse graphs (where $M = o(N^2)$).

Bellow I provide C++ code for this algorithm too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 105  // Maximum number of friends possible

vector<int> E[MAXN];  // Adjacency lists
// y is in E[x] vector iff x knows y

list<int> H[MAXN];  // The array of lists
// x is in H[i] iff x is currently invited and knows exactly i currently invited people

list<int>::iterator IT[MAXN];
// the iterator array, this gives you the position of each guest on the proper list

int K[MAXN];  // array that stores how many current guests does someone know

bool INV[MAXN];  // INV[x] = true iff x is invited to the party

queue<int> Q;
// Queue with the ids of the guests that should be removed

int main()
{
    // Reding input and initializations...
    int N;  // Number of your friends
    // Assume ids in range 0 to N-1 inclusive
    cin >> N;
    int M;  // Number of connections
    cin >> M;

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        // x and y know each other
        E[x].push_back(y);
        E[y].push_back(x);
        // Increase the number of guests that x and y know by one
        K[x]++;
        K[y]++;
    }

    // Initially everyone is assumed to be invited
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) INV[i] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int k = K[i];  // i-th friend knows k people
        H[k].push_front(i);  // save i-th person's id in the appropriate list
        IT[i] = H[k].begin();  // save an iterator of current person's address in H[k]
    }

    int L = N;  // Initially all N guests remain in the party

    // Find guests that should be removed (phase 1)...
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (K[i] < 3 || K[i] >= N - 3)
    {
        // person with id i should be removed from the guests
        Q.push(i);
        INV[i] = false;
    }
    // Clear respective lists
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) H[i].clear();
    for (int i = max(3, L - 3); i < N; i++) H[i].clear();

    // Remove guests until the party is ok for everyone
    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        int rem_guest = Q.front();  // Id of a guest that we should remove
        Q.pop();
        L--;  // Decrease the number of remaining guests by one
        for (int i = 0; i < E[rem_guest].size(); i++) if (INV[E[rem_guest][i]])
        {
            int id = E[rem_guest][i];  // id of a current guest that rem_guest knows
            // The number of known guests for current guest is decreased
            K[id]--;
            // change the list of the current guest
            H[K[id] + 1].erase(IT[id]);
            H[K[id]].push_front(id);
            IT[id] = H[K[id]].begin();
        }
        // Every guest with 2 or L-3 known guests should be removed later
        for (list<int>::iterator it = H[2].begin(); it != H[2].end(); it++)
        {
            // The party is improper for current guest
            // Save his id in the queue to remove him/her later
            Q.push(*it);
            INV[*it] = false;  // The guest should not be invited
        }
        H[2].clear();  // remove everyone from 2nd list
        if (L - 3 >= 0)
        {
            for (list<int>::iterator it = H[L - 3].begin(); it != H[L - 3].end(); it++)
            {
                // The party is improper for current guest
                // Save his id in the queue to remove him/her later
                Q.push(*it);
                INV[*it] = false;  // The guest should not be invited
            }
            H[L - 3].clear();  // remove everyone from 2nd list
        }
    }

    // L people remain invited
    // Display answer
    cout << L << '\n';

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @Apass.Jack what do you want to say? Does exist linear complexity for this task?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thank you for the corrections. I edited the post. I also thought of a linear $O(N + M)$ algorithm which I now describe in detail.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко Yes, there is an algorithm with linear complexity for your problem. See the edit of my answer.